# How to fix row grid view product with fix size?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

please help me..i have a problem with the size of my content product.i want to make some grid of food but the grid not at same size..i want fix it to same size and look good on mobile too..plis help me

[image: This is my interface]

```css
.product-grid4, .product-grid4 .product-image4 {
    position: relative
}

.product-grid4 {
    font-family: Poppins,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all .3s ease 0s
}

    .product-grid4:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2)
    }

    .product-grid4 .product-image4 a {
        display: block
    }

    .product-grid4 .product-image4 img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto
    }

    .product-grid4 .pic-1 {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all .5s ease-out 0s
    }

    .product-grid4 .product-discount-label, .product-grid4 .product-new-label {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #16a085;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 800;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        width: 45px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 15px;
        transition: all .3s
    }

    .product-grid4 .product-discount-label {
        left: auto;
        right: 10px;
        background-color: #d7292a
    }

    .product-grid4 .product-content {
        padding: 25px
    }

    .product-grid4 .title {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        margin: 0 0 7px;
        transition: all .3s ease 0s
    }

        .product-grid4 .title a {
            color: #222
        }

    .product-grid4 .price {
        color: #16a085;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin: 0 2px 15px 0;
        display: block
    }

        .product-grid4 .price span {
            color: #909090;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 400;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            text-decoration: line-through;
            text-align: left;
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: inline-block
        }

    .product-grid4 .add-to-cart {
        border: 1px solid #16a085;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        color: #fff;
        background: #16a085;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 14px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        transition: all .3s
    }


 
@media only screen and (max-width:990px) {
    .product-grid4 {
        margin-bottom: 30px
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="product-grid4">
                    <div class="product-image4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="pic-1" src="img/pic1.jpg">
                        </a>
                        <span class="product-new-label">New</span>
                        <span class="product-discount-label">50%</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <h3 class="title">Burger Bosku</h3>
                        <div class="price">
                           RM 10.00
                            <span>RM 20.00</span>
                        </div>
                        <button class="add-to-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCart">+ Add To Cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="product-grid4">
                    <div class="product-image4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="pic-1" src="img/pic2.jpg">
                        </a>
                        <span class="product-discount-label">50%</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <h3 class="title">Pasta Special</h3>
                        <div class="price">
                            RM 15.00
                            <span>RM 30.00</span>
                        </div>
                        <button class="add-to-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCart">+ Add To Cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="product-grid4">
                    <div class="product-image4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="pic-1" src="img/pic4.jpg">
                        </a>
                        <span class="product-new-label">New</span>
                        <span class="product-discount-label">10%</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <h3 class="title"><a href="#">Pizza Pizzi</a></h3>
                        <div class="price">
                            RM 9.00
                            <span>RM 10.00</span>
                        </div>
                        <button class="add-to-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCart">+ Add To Cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="product-grid4">
                    <div class="product-image4">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="pic-1" src="img/pic7.jpg">
                        </a>
                        <span class="product-new-label">New</span>
                        <span class="product-discount-label">20%</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <h3 class="title">Sweet Food</h3>
                        <div class="price">
                            RM 18.00
                            <span>RM 20.00</span>
                        </div>
                        <button class="add-to-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCart">+ Add To Cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
```

how can i fix this..i think its all about the css but i dont know what i must change.please help me.

Comment: Did you tried my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the images to be of the same size, try adding the following to your CSS

```
.pic-1 {
        min-height:100px
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the column flex to align equal height. I just set the min-height for your class `.product-grid4 .product-image4 img`. You can adjust the min-height based on your requirement.

```css
.product-grid4,
.product-grid4 .product-image4 {
    position: relative
}

.product-grid4 {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

.product-grid4:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)
}

.product-grid4 .product-image4 a {
    display: block
}

.product-grid4 .product-image4 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.product-grid4 .pic-1 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .5s ease-out 0s
}

.product-grid4 .product-discount-label,
.product-grid4 .product-new-label {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #16a085;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 15px;
    transition: all .3s
}

.product-grid4 .product-discount-label {
    left: auto;
    right: 10px;
    background-color: #d7292a
}

.product-grid4 .product-content {
    padding: 25px
}
@media (min-width: 501px) {
.product-grid4 .product-image4 img {
    min-height: 330px;
}
}
@media (min-width:991px) {
.product-grid4 .product-image4 img {
    min-height: 260px;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div class="product-grid4">
                <div class="product-image4">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
                    </a>
                    <span class="product-new-label">New</span>
                    <span class="product-discount-label">50%</span>
                </div>
                <div class="product-content">
                    <h3 class="title">Burger Bosku</h3>
                    <div class="price">
                        RM 10.00
                        <span>RM 20.00</span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="add-to-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCart">+ Add To Cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div class="product-grid4">
                <div class="product-image4">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/550x150">
                    </a>
                    <span class="product-discount-label">50%</span>
                </div>
                <div class="product-content">
                    <h3 class="title">Pasta Special</h3>
                    <div class="price">
                        RM 15.00
                        <span>RM 30.00</span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="add-to-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCart">+ Add To Cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div class="product-grid4">
                <div class="product-image4">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
                    </a>
                    <span class="product-new-label">New</span>
                    <span class="product-discount-label">10%</span>
                </div>
                <div class="product-content">
                    <h3 class="title"><a href="#">Pizza Pizzi</a></h3>
                    <div class="price">
                        RM 9.00
                        <span>RM 10.00</span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="add-to-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCart">+ Add To Cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div class="product-grid4">
                <div class="product-image4">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
                    </a>
                    <span class="product-new-label">New</span>
                    <span class="product-discount-label">20%</span>
                </div>
                <div class="product-content">
                    <h3 class="title">Sweet Food</h3>
                    <div class="price">
                        RM 18.00
                        <span>RM 20.00</span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="add-to-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCart">+ Add To Cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works perfectly thanks but on mobile view the image look so stretchy and when i adjust using this below code the grid not on their row.....i want to make it look good on desktop and mobile view........................                                                                                   
 @media only screen and (max-width:500px) {
    .product-grid4 {
        margin-bottom: 30px
    }

        .product-grid4 .product-image4 img {
            min-height: 100px;
        }
}

Comment: I have updated the code based on responsive. You can adjust the `min-height` within the written media queries.

Comment: okay its work thank you so much..i think it not good when i adjust too small for bigger resolution screen haha..thanks.

Comment: I can adjust become all screen same height without min-height but image will be cutoff smaller between top and bottom.